# Store cache images

Tags: iphone, objective-c, image, core-data

I'm looking for the best read performance for a bunch (~200) cached 80px by 80px images. A large chuck (~50) will all needed to be accessed at once.

Should I store the uiimages (as binary data) in a plist or using core data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A couple of basic concepts:

- CoreData is probably the worst way to go for the image data, the documentation states that BLOB segments in the store cause massive performance problems.
- Use the file system for what it's built for, read / write access of random chunks of data.

The rest depends on how you organize your data, so here are some thoughts:

- 80x80 is pretty small, you could probably hold 50 or so in memory at a given time.
- You need a way to hash the images into some kind of structure so you know which ones to fetch. I would use core data for storing the locations of the images on the file system, and back your view with an NSFetchedResultsController to pull out the list of file names.
- Use some in memory data structure to store the UIImage objects, a FIFO queue with a size of 50 would work well here, as it gets a new image from the file system it pops out the oldest one.
- Finally you have to know what images you're going to view and stay ahead of it, file system reads won't be super fast, so you'll need to either chunk your reads or stay far enough of your view to avoid lagging.  If your view is showing 50, you might want to keep 100 in memory, 50+ 25 previous and 25 next if you're scrolling for example.

A premature optimization:

- If read performance is essential, it would be worth while to store the images in "page" sized chunks, such as a zip of 5 or n images that can be read into memory at once, and then split into their corresponding UIImage files.

Comment: I'd recommend an NSDictionary.  Assuming your data model is CoreData, you can store the images in the Dictionary with the pointer value as the key e.g. `[imageThumbnails objectForKey:[NSNumber numberWithInt:(int)referenceObject]]`  Wabbits is completely correct about performance concerns - if you don't stay ahead of a tableview and are hitting the file system while they scroll it will be a huge hit.  80x80 thumbs can easily be preloaded in one chunk.

Comment: @Michael, an NSDictionary is a good solution is the data is loaded in one chunk, however NSMutableDictionary is not threadsafe and may have issues if you try to limit how many images are actually in memory at a given time.

Comment: @Wabbits, true enough.  In my own solution I actually build up the objects with a mutable dictionary and then store it as a non-mutable.  I've found that you can load tons of thumbnails in there without consuming very much memory.

Comment: @Michael so are you suggesting storing the binary image data in a dictionary plist or just storing file references in the dictionary?

Comment: I think it depends on the size/implementation of your particular application.  For me, I have tableviews with custom cells that have lots of diverse and large images that are reduced to fit.  I have found that I can cache the UIImages directly with very little memory hit (couple megs).  That said if you don't have a tableview that you need to fly performance wise, file references in a dictionary is probably the better way to go.  I haven't needed to optimize my memory model yet, so I don't know the performance impact.

Comment: I'll be using a uiscrollview/paging implementation and I want it to fly so I think it would be best to store images in a dictionary plist. I'll be needing all ~50 images at once and the order is highly unlikely to changed too.